# Implementing a "Roll Table" data structure

Tags: java, object-oriented, game

I am trying to implement a helper program for a paper RPG game. In this game, there are a lot of "roll tables". Basically, those are tables which associates the result of a dice roll to a concrete result.

For example, you could have something like that:

```
    1 | Roll is 1
2 - 5 | Roll is between 2 and 5
6 - 7 | Roll is either 6 or 7
8 - 9 | Roll is either 8 or 9
   10 | Roll is 10
```

Since there are so much of those tables, I'm trying to implement a generic data structure to match it. In the future, they should be able to

- Use incremental rolls, with each concrete result add a bonus or penalty to the next roll
- Add conditions, which means a same dice roll could match different concrete results depending on a condition

The roll tables are all defined by a generic interface :

```
public interface RollTable<E> {

    void addRollEntry(RollTableEntry<E> rollEntry);

    void addRollEntries(Collection<RollTableEntry<E>> rollEntries);

    E rollOnTable() throws RollTableInvalidException;

    E rollOnTable(int diceSize) throws RollTableInvalidException;

}
```

Each entry of the RollTable is represented by a RollTableEntry, generic as well. Equals has been redefined to make sure there is no overlaps between the different entries of a RollTable

```
/**
 * Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals.
 *
 *
 * @param <E>
 */
public class RollTableEntry<E> implements Comparable<RollTableEntry<E>> {

    private final int minRoll, maxRoll;
    private final E concreteValue;


    public RollTableEntry(int singleRoll, E concreteValue) {
        this(singleRoll, singleRoll, concreteValue);
    }

    public RollTableEntry(int minRoll, int maxRoll, E concreteValue) {
        this.minRoll = minRoll < maxRoll ? minRoll : maxRoll;
        this.maxRoll = maxRoll > minRoll ? maxRoll : minRoll;
        this.concreteValue = concreteValue;
    }

    public boolean isRollAMatch(int rollValue) {
        return minRoll <= rollValue && rollValue <= maxRoll;
    }

    public int getMinRoll() {
        return minRoll;
    }

    public int getMaxRoll() {
        return maxRoll;
    }

    public E getConcreteValue() {
        return concreteValue;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(RollTableEntry<E> o) {
        return minRoll - o.minRoll;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(minRoll, maxRoll);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (obj instanceof RollTableEntry<?>) {
            RollTableEntry<?> other = (RollTableEntry<?>) obj;
            if (overlaps(other)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        String rangeRoll = (minRoll == maxRoll) ? String.valueOf(minRoll) : (minRoll + " - " + maxRoll);
        builder.append(String.format("%9s", rangeRoll)).append(" | ").append(concreteValue);
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private boolean overlaps(RollTableEntry<?> other) {
        return minRoll <= other.maxRoll && other.minRoll <= maxRoll;
    }

}
```

The SimpleRollTable is the simplest implementation of the RollTable interface (and the only one so far). The validity of the table is checked and updated on every insertion to make sure that every possible dice roll is matched to a concrete result.

```
public class SimpleRollTable<E> implements RollTable<E> {

    private static final int DEFAULT_DICE_SIZE = 10;
    private final int diceSize;

    private boolean rollTableValid;

    private SortedSet<RollTableEntry<E>> rollEntries;


    public SimpleRollTable() {
        this(DEFAULT_DICE_SIZE);
    }

    public SimpleRollTable(int diceSize) {
        this.diceSize = diceSize;
        this.rollEntries = new TreeSet<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void addRollEntries(Collection<RollTableEntry<E>> newRollEntries) {
        rollEntries.addAll(newRollEntries);
        checkValidity();
    }

    @Override
    public void addRollEntry(RollTableEntry<E> rollEntry) {
        rollEntries.add(rollEntry);
        checkValidity();
    }

    @Override
    public E rollOnTable() throws RollTableInvalidException {
        return rollOnTable(diceSize);
    }

    @Override
    public E rollOnTable(int diceSize) throws RollTableInvalidException {
        if (!rollTableValid) {
            throw new RollTableInvalidException();
        }
        int diceRoll = DiceUtils.roll(diceSize);
        E concreteValue = null;
        for (RollTableEntry<E> rollEntry : rollEntries) {
            if (rollEntry.isRollAMatch(diceRoll)) {
                concreteValue = rollEntry.getConcreteValue();
            }
        }
        return concreteValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder("Simple Roll Table of size " + diceSize).append("\n\n");
        for (RollTableEntry<E> rollEntry : rollEntries) {
            builder.append(rollEntry).append('\n');
        }
        return builder.toString();
    }

    private void checkValidity() {
        for (int i = 1 ; i <= diceSize ; i++) {
            if (!isMatchingEntry(i)) {
                rollTableValid = false;
                return;
            }
        }
        rollTableValid = true;
    }

    private boolean isMatchingEntry(int diceRoll) {
        for (RollTableEntry<E> rollEntry : rollEntries) {
            if (rollEntry.isRollAMatch(diceRoll)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Finally, a Factory will be used to build the tables.

```
public enum RollTableFactory {

    FACTORY;

    public RollTable<String> getTestRollTable() {
        RollTable<String> rollTable = new SimpleRollTable<>();
        Set<RollTableEntry<String>> rollEntries = new HashSet<>();

        rollEntries.add(new RollTableEntry<String>(1, "Roll is 1"));
        rollEntries.add(new RollTableEntry<String>(2, 5, "Roll is between 2 and 5"));
        rollEntries.add(new RollTableEntry<String>(6, 7, "Roll is either 6 or 7"));
        rollEntries.add(new RollTableEntry<String>(8, 9, "Roll is either 8 or 9"));
        rollEntries.add(new RollTableEntry<String>(10, "Roll is 10"));
        rollTable.addRollEntries(rollEntries);
        return rollTable;
    }

}
```

So far, I only implemented the simplest version of a RollTable, and I would like your opinion on the choices I've made, so I can be sure I'm heading in the right direction before adding more functionalities. Thanks for your help

**EDIT**

I edit this question since I realize that my intentions are not very clear. Basically, what I call a roll table is a structure that will associate an integer value, obtained with a dice roll to *something*.

That something can be pretty much anything, hence the generic aspect of the structure. It could return the weather for the next two hours, the enemies you face, the name of a NPC... You name it. Some table might also ask you to roll a dice on another table.

I've actually changed my implementation a fair bit since asking the question, I switched to a SortedMap implementation, which is way easier to use, I'll probably do a follow-up question once I'm done with the other functionalities.

Follow-up question : [Follow-up on a RollTable data-structure](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/173743/follow-up-on-a-rolltable-data-structure)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not entirely sure what the roll table actually represents. My initial thought was a simple lookup that maps a dice roll to some generic result (like a String message). But your implementation shows that it's more like a special kind of dice that has those generic results on it's sides.

Here's the steps I would expect on how the tables would be used based on your initial specifications:

Choose the correct die/dice (based on table max?)
-> roll those dice
-> apply modifications
-> pass the modified dice result to a lookup table to get the generic roll outcome

This means that the entire dice rolling should be factored out of your roll table class.

---

The way you construct the tables also feels a bit lacking.

Imagine having 50 of those tables where one of them had a typo so there's no outcome for roll value `5`. You start the program without problems and use it in one of your games. Having some bad(?) luck you don't use this table until near the end of the game. It's only at that point that your entire program will crash (or something a bit less drastic depending on how you handle the error).

I suggest to use a **builder pattern** while constructing the table and then initialise the actual RollTable entirely in it's constructor. That way you can easily check correctness when you load up all the tables instead of when you accidentally run into a mistake.

I also suggest to only pass the upper bound of the range at each step (and assume an ordered definition of the table). The lower bound will always be 1 higher than the upperbound of the previous range. Your example table would then look like this:

```
1  | Roll is 1
5  | Roll is between 2 and 5
7  | Roll is either 6 or 7
9  | Roll is either 8 or 9
10 | Roll is 10
```

Depending on what you intend to do with the conditions (and thus allowing some form of overlap) you could even remove your RollTableEntry class entirely and change table to simple `SortedMap<Integer, E>` instead. The lookup then just searches for the first key that is larger than the diceroll.

---

Depending on whether or not it makes sense for your games, you can also assume the last range to be "infinite". So that if you have some bonus modifications that increase your dice roll over what the table is inteded to, you just return the "largest" result instead.

---

Since you speak of a large number of tables, it could also be beneficial to read them from a file. Choose an encoding to your liking (for example JSON, XML, ...) that you can parse relatively easy and instantiate the tables from there.

You can also provide a factory method on the RollTable class that takes a certain config block (for example a part of the XML that contains that specific roll table) instead of using the builder pattern.

---

As a final note I want to point out again that this entire answer makes a bunch of assumptions on what your code is supposed to do. It's possible that it doesn't really fit your intentions.

Comment: I like this suggestion. I'm imagining code something like this, for the same rolltable as in the example: `RollTableEntry<String> result = RolltableBuilder.withMax(10).step(1, "Roll is 1").step(5, "Roll table is 2-5").step(7, "Roll table is 6-7").step(9, "Roll is either 8 or 9").finalStep("Roll is 10")`

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've edited the question to (hopefully) be clearer. I really like the Builder Pattern idea as well, but it could be a bit cumbersome since most tables I need to use represent around 50 possibilities. The JSON route might be a better idea after all. I've actually switched to a SortedMap<Integer, E> implementation since asking the question, when I realized my first idea was ... quite awful to maintain

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm looking forward to seeing your folow-up review question. It would be nice that when you post your new version, you edit this one to link to the new question. And awesome if you ping me here when you do, so I can take a look at it as well.

Comment: @SimonForsberg I would probably not include the `.withMax(..)` and have that last step inserted like any other step. Then finish of with a `.build()` wich takes the value of the last step as the `max`. Especially when reading from a file this makes it easier since you don't know whether a certain line is the last one or not until you try to read the next one.